# Jquery Ajax woking only once

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
function postData() {
    var fName=$("#fName").val();
    var lName=$("#lName").val();
    var city=$("#city").val();
    var data="fName="+fName+"&lName="+lName+"&city="+city+"&submit=submit";
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'employeeajaxcodebehind.php',
        data:data,
        success:function(data){
        $("#results").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Php Code below

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $fName=$_POST['fName'];
    $lName=$_POST['lName'];
    $city=$_POST['city'];
    $Query="INSERT INTO employee(emp_id,firstname,lastname,city) VALUES ('','$fName','$lName','$city')";
    $Result=mysql_query($Query);
    viewRecord();
}
```

Html:

```
<form method="POST">
    Firstname: <input type="text" id="fName" name="fName"><br>
    Lastname: <input type="text" id="lName" name="lName"><br>
    City: <input type="text" id="city" name="city"><br>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" onclick="postData();">
</form>
```

Now problem is that whenever I open the page I insert one record and its getting saved successfully on my DB. But when I add another record its not getting saved... I have to reload the page on every insert...

Whats is the problem here? Also the php function `viewRecord();` should be executed but its not...

Comment: Where is the HTML / your form?

Comment: how is postData called?

Comment: check please now .. i've added html

Comment: try by putting `return false` on `onSubmit` event of form

Comment: Side note: your code is insecure and using a deprecated database function. Google "SQL injection" and check out the current `mysqli` set of PHP functions.

Comment: Lol why everyone is forcing me to get into mysqli :\ i don't even know mysql yet :S i'm a newbie

Comment: Using mysqli doesn't make your code secure but yes moving to mysqli and then implementing improved SQL functions that prevent injection will help

Comment: @RameezShah mysql is deprecated which means that it will not be available in future version of PHP. mysqli is a direct replacement for this - use it in exactly the same way but if you do it is prone to sql injection as mentioned above

Comment: oh means it has same functions ?

Comment: You wouldn't want to get a little Bobby Tables on your hands.. http://littlebobbytables.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to get data from form.

Also your form send data two times - at onclick and onsubmit. Please prevent onsubmit event by adding `return false;`

Comment: i Don't know how to use serialize() as this is the very first jquery work i'm dong... 

I should remove if(isset($_POST['submit']) ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are adding the emp_id as blank (if it is not a primary key or unique key). You need to omit this in the sql:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO employee(firstname,lastname,city) VALUES ('$fName','$lName','$city')";
```

JS Changes: as you are using submit button. you need to prevent the page not to refresh. So change your ajax call like this one:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    /* attach a submit handler to the form */
    $("#commentForm").submit(function(event) {

      /* stop form from submitting normally */
      event.preventDefault();

      /* get some values from elements on the page: */
      var $form = $( this ),
      var url =  "employeeajaxcodebehind.php" // or $form.attr( 'action' );

      /* Send the data using post */
      var posting = $.post( url, { fName: $('#fName').val(), lName: $('#lName').val(), city: $('#city').val() } );

      /* Put the results in a div */
      posting.done(function( data ) {
        $("#results").html(data);
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: then use the query that i have write in my answer. it will work fine. check it

Comment: if you define a primary key then it should not save the null value into it. (if you define a unique key, it will take a null value only once).

Comment: No but its autoincrement :S

Comment: have to tried the above query? Yes, it should be an autoincreament.

Comment: one more this, replace your submit button with normal button.

Comment: I can't do this because in my PHp i've used isset ($_POST['submit']))

Comment: I think the main problem is the return false thing :S

Comment: changing the query makes no difference bro :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem as @skparwal mentioned is that you are trying to insert '' into your primary key. You need to use `mysql_error()` after your insert to see what errors occur. Have a look at this link on how to do this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Also, your ajax won't work as expected because you are not returning false for onClick() which means that the form is being submitted each time after the ajax call gets triggered.

Furthermore, you should be moving to mysqli or PDO because mysql is deprecated.

**Edit**

Try this **but it is not meant to work or be a final implementation,** it is just to get you on the right path. It is untested so there might be some errors:

Change your javascript to this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#submit').click(postData);
});

function postData() {
    var fName=$("#fName").val();
    var lName=$("#lName").val();
    var city=$("#city").val();
    var data="fName="+fName+"&lName="+lName+"&city="+city+"&submit=submit";
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'employeeajaxcodebehind.php',
        data:data,
        success:function(data){
            $("#results").html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Change your PHP to this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $fName=$_POST['fName'];
    $lName=$_POST['lName'];
    $city=$_POST['city'];
    $Query="INSERT INTO employee(firstname,lastname,city) VALUES ('$fName','$lName','$city')";
    if( !( $Result=mysql_query($Query) ) )
        exit( '@todo need to check for error here' );
    viewRecord();
}
```

Change your HTML to this:

```
<form method="POST">
    Firstname: <input type="text" id="fName" name="fName"><br>
    Lastname: <input type="text" id="lName" name="lName"><br>
    City: <input type="text" id="city" name="city"><br>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to return false ?

Comment: Yeahhhhhhh :D Workinggg fine... even the function viewRecord(); is working... what was i doing wrong :S my teacher taugth me that way :S